# How to run shake without stack

Tags: haskell, cabal-install, shake-build-system, cabal-new

I created the recommended `build.sh` file from the ["Running" section of the Shake manual](https://shakebuild.com/manual#compiling-the-build-system):

```sh
#!/bin/sh
mkdir -p _shake
ghc --make Shakefile.hs -v -rtsopts -threaded -with-rtsopts=-I0 -outputdir=_shake -o _shake/build && _shake/build "$@"
```

but running that script gives the following error:

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( Shakefile.hs, _shake/Main.o )

Shakefile.hs:1:1: error:
    Could not find module ‘Development.Shake’
    Use -v (or `:set -v` in ghci) to see a list of the files searched for.
  |
1 | import Development.Shake
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Shakefile.hs:2:1: error:
    Could not find module ‘Development.Shake.Command’
    Use -v (or `:set -v` in ghci) to see a list of the files searched for.
  |
2 | import Development.Shake.Command
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Shakefile.hs:3:1: error:
    Could not find module ‘Development.Shake.FilePath’
    Use -v (or `:set -v` in ghci) to see a list of the files searched for.
  |
3 | import Development.Shake.FilePath
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Shakefile.hs:4:1: error:
    Could not find module ‘Development.Shake.Util’
    Use -v (or `:set -v` in ghci) to see a list of the files searched for.
  |
4 | import Development.Shake.Util
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I did `cabal v2-install shake --installpath=bin`, but still get the same error afterwards.  I also tried `bin/shake` but get the same error.

I tried adding `-package shake` to the `ghc` command in the `build.sh`, but get this error:

```
<command line>: cannot satisfy -package shake
    (use -v for more information)
```

Adding `-v` as suggested gives this error:

```
Glasgow Haskell Compiler, Version 8.8.4, stage 2 booted by GHC version 8.8.3
Using binary package database: /Users/avh4/.ghcup/ghc/8.8.4/lib/ghc-8.8.4/package.conf.d/package.cache
package flags [-package shake{package shake True ([])}]
loading package database /Users/avh4/.ghcup/ghc/8.8.4/lib/ghc-8.8.4/package.conf.d
<command line>: cannot satisfy -package shake
    (use -v for more information)
```

What is the correct way to use Shake without [Haskell stack](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/README/) (preferably using only ghc 8.8 installed with `ghcup` and/or with cabal-install v2 commands)?

Answer (score 4):

I figured out I need to use the `--lib` flag with `cabal new-install` otherwise only the shake binary gets installed.

After running `cabal new-install --lib shake`, the original `build.sh` script with the addition of `-package shake` to the `ghc` arguments now works!  And `runhaskell -package shake Shakefile.hs` also works now.